# How to make MYSAPSSO2 cookie persistent

Tags: cookies, sapui5, persistent, sap-fiori, sap-basis

We are having a SAP Fiori app with SSO configured. By default, the MYSAPSSO2 cookie is not-persistent, causing the need to login every time we open the browser.

Is there a may to make the MYSAPSSO2 cookie persistent?

Answer (score 2):

SAP Logon Tickets are time-restricted, thus they should not be persisted.
This would also be a serious security issue.

If you would like to have automated logon, you might look into X.509 client certificates or SPNego.